# Mockito doesn't match a method argument any() type

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito 1.10.19 to test a method call. I have some classes that invokes an `execute` method

```
public class Argument {
  public D execute(B b){
    return new D();
  }
}
class A extends B {
}
class B {
}
class C extends B {
}
class D {}
```

tests

```
public class ArgumentTest {
  @Test
  public void execute() throws Exception {
    Argument argument = mock(Argument.class);
    A a = mock(A.class);
    D d = mock(D.class);
    when(argument.execute(any(A.class))).thenAnswer(
        (invocation) -> {
          Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
          Object mock = invocation.getMock();
          return d;
        }
    );

    argument.execute(new C());
  }

}
```

When I run this test it matches `when` matcher even if argument `any(A.class)`.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no type checking in `any(...)` - [source](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any(java.lang.Class)):

> This method *doesn't do any type checks*, it is only there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

Quick glance into the source code shows us that the matching succeeds for *any* kind of argument, and the class parameter is used only for generating default return value.

```
public static <T> T any(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) reportMatcher(Any.ANY).returnFor(clazz);
}
```

---

It also may make method overloads with equal number of parameters hard(er) to test.
That could be avoided with `argThat` matcher that does an explicit `instanceof` check though.

Comment: 6 years later, but question and answer are version-specific;
newer flavours of Mockito since 2.1.0 do type checks in `any(Class)` - e.g. Javadoc in 4.4.0 even states that it's an alias for `isAClass`